# Capturing the output of an external call as a string (in Chez Scheme)

Tags: string, scheme, port, chez-scheme

Using Chez Scheme, I tried to capture the output of an external command into a string port (see https://www.scheme.com/csug8/io.html):

```
(define output 
  (with-output-to-string (lambda () (system "ls -a")))
  )
```

The output of `(system "ls -a")` is displayed on the screen, and `output` is empty (tested as a script with chezscheme 9.5.4 on Linux).

The same code works correctly with Racket 8.3 [CS].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works with Chez Scheme 9.5.8 on Linux.

```lisp
(define (capture-standard-output command)
  (let-values ([(in out err pid) (open-process-ports command 'block
                                   (make-transcoder (utf-8-codec)))])
    (get-string-all out)))


(capture-standard-output "ls -a")  ;; => ".\n..\nbar\nfoo\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(define output
  (get-string-all (car (process "ls -a"))))
```

seems to work on MacOS

Comment: This works also under Linux. Yet, the difference between `system` and `process` is that "the `system` procedure waits for the process to exit before returning, ... while the `process` procedure returns immediately without waiting for the process to exit." <http://cisco.github.io/ChezScheme/csug9.5/foreign.html>

Comment: Is there a way to wait for the process to exit (like what `system` does)?

Comment: `open-process-ports` ? (wait for end-of-file?)

Comment: Could you please explain, with code, how to start the process and how to wait for the `EOF`?